# Please grammatically analyze the structure of this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I quote this from [MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/why-dlc-and-season-passes-are-here-to-stay/) site.

> So, really, you'd be paying way, way upwards of the $70 price-tag
> games are going to be sold for.

I can't find out the structure of this sentence, and further more, don't know whether it's a **sentence** or not.

What I can do is..

- You : Subject
- 'd  : auxiliary verb
- be paying : verb(intransitive?)
- way, way upwards of (adjective)

after 'of': 'the $70 price-tag games are going to be sold for.' should be a phrase, but this is clause. I couldn't figure the structure of this sentence out.

Comment: It's the same as "So, really, you'd be paying way, way upwards of the $70 price-tag that games are going to be sold for." There are several questions on here about that-deletion which should explain more.

Comment: 'So' and 'really' are pragmatic markers ... the first a connective, possibly explanatory, and the second modal or veridical (expressing an estimate of probability / accuracy).